# Dynamics CRM 2011 attach file with SDK

Tags: c#, file, attachment, dynamics-crm-2011

I saw a feature in Dynamics CRM 2011 of attaching file to an entity with user interface. 
How I can attach file using Dynimcs CRM SDK 2011 and C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to attach a file to an entity programmatically, it must first have Notes enabled on the entity (`HasNotes` is `true`).

Then, create an `Annotation` entity record (more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334398.aspx).  To associate it to a specific record, use an `AssociateRequest` (more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.associaterequest.aspx).

There is a sample of at least creating an annotation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328429.aspx.

Comment: @Nozim Actually, that article says that `AssignUserRolesRole` was removed and that you should use `AssociateRequest` instead...  The documentation I linked in the answer is for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.

Comment: rather than explicitly using Relationship =
                                                         new Relationship("teamprofiles_association")  is there a way to just call it in an early bound way, for example we know that entitylogicalname we can just get like this: Account.EntityLogicalName, but how do we get the relationship in the similar style?